# Difficulty in accessing parent page from user control

Tags: c#, gridview, user-controls

I am developing a reusable pager user control that can be embedded  in any page where that particular functionality is required.

But , I am facing a difficulty i.e

```
protected void LoadDataPageWise(int iCurrentPage)
{
   grdPages.PageIndex = iCurrentPage - 1;
   liGridItems = (List<string>)p.FindControl("liGridItems");
   grdPages.DataSource = liGridItems;
   grdPages.DataBind();
   DisplayPageNumber();
}
```

But, the data source for grid view is in Parent page where the user control is embedded. How can i bind my grid view with that collection.

I am having all my functionality of paging in User control. I am accessing grid view which is in the parent page as:

```
Page p = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
GridView grdPages=(GridView)p.FindControl("grdPages");
```

This is how i have written in Page Load of user control: how can i re write this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iPagesPerSet = int.Parse(ddlnoofpagesperset.SelectedValue);
            p = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            grdPages=(GridView)p.FindControl("grdPages");
            iPageCount = grdPages.PageCount;
            lnkbtnForwardTriggerPager.Text = "Next " + iPagesPerSet + " pages";
            lnkbtnBackwardTriggerPager.Text = "Previous " + iPagesPerSet + " pages";

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadDataPageWise(iCurrentPage);
                LoadInitialPager();
                imgbtnFirst.Enabled = false;
                imgbtnPrevious.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: You really want to hard-wire your usercontrol in this way? What if the page doesn't contain a `gridView` anymore or someone changes it's ID? You shoudl let the page control the `UserControl` and not vice-versa. Therefore provide public properties and methods.

Comment: Can you Please explain @ Time Schmelter

Comment: can you try find the gridview with a recursive "findcontrol" method.